Filter polygons to find those which can contain specific dimensions
I have a dataset containing a large amount of polygons which act as potential locations for someone to park a van. To find the polygons that are suitable, they must be able to contain a 11.5 x 6.3 metre dimension rectangle at any angle.
I thought at first maybe just search for the polygons >72.45m2 however this obviously wouldn't work due to polygons with irregular shapes such as long and thin etc.
I tried to use QGIS to extract vertices of each polygon and use the distance matrix tool to find the longest connection but this is difficult to automate with the Graphical Modeller.
How could I achieve this using ArcGIS Pro or QGIS?

Can the rectangle be rotated or does it need to be on the horizontal? Question like this are best supported with images of what you want. Suggest you edit your question to include these.

You can use methods described at Finding the major axis of a polygon (the outline of a sinkhole or doline) to draw lines between the most distant points within each polygon, then divide the polygon area by the length of those lines to back out the semi-minor axis.
Once you have done this you can filter the polygons based on the conditions you describe (semimajor axis > 11.5m & semi-minor axis > 6.3m).
